# SQL query for count all(unknown, known), unknown, known customer

Tags: sql

```
Id, CustomerId, IsKnownCustomer,phonemacaddress

1,  NULL         0              00:9a:34:cf:a4
2,  004024       1              00:6f:64:cf:a0:93 
3,  004024       1              00:6f:64:cf:a0:93
4,  004003       1              2c:0e:3d:15:12:43
6,  NULL         0              2c:0e:3d:15:125
7,  004003       1              34:f3:9a:ee:53:a9
8,  004023       1              38:0B:40:DC:BA:3A
9,  NULL         0              4c:66:41:11:26:16
```

This is the table, and data is required for all customer, unknown customer and known customer.

output like: uniquely find the records by phonemacaddress.

```
count Customer, customer type  
7                 all
3                 unknown customer
4                 known customer
```

Comment: GROUP BY. Use case expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT phonemacaddress) [count Customer] , 
    CASE 
        WHEN GROUPING(IsKnownCustomer) = 1 THEN 'all' 
        WHEN IsKnownCustomer = 1 THEN 'known customer' 
        WHEN IsKnownCustomer = 0 THEN 'unknown customer' END [customer type] 
FROM @CustomerTable
GROUP BY IsKnownCustomer WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY GROUPING(IsKnownCustomer) DESC, IsKnownCustomer
```

Result:

```
count Customer customer type
-------------- ----------------
7              all
3              unknown customer
4              known customer
```

Comment: It should be based on phonemacaddress..The output is different from expected output

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select count(Id), 'All' as customer_type  from customers
union
select count(Id), 'Unknown' as customer_type  from customers
WHERE isKnownCustomer =0
union
select count(Id), 'known' as customer_type  from customers
WHERE isKnownCustomer =1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e7616/15